# I want to set date into my html date field. I have used mutator in Laravel, Now how can I set date in the date field to edit a record?

Tags: html, laravel, date, laravel-5.5, mutators

This is My mutator in my model..

```
protected $dates = ['closer_date','final_submission_date','start_date'];
```

This is a field where I want to set the dates in the fields retrieving record from database.

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="start_date" value="{{ $topic->start_date}}" id = "start_date" onkeyup = "Validate(this)" required min=<?php
                                    echo date('Y-m-d');
                                    ?> />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `format()` to set the format

```
{{ $topic->start_date->format('Y-m-d')}}
```

in Your code

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="start_date" value="{{ $topic->start_date->format('Y-m-d)}}" id = "start_date" onkeyup = "Validate(this)" required min=<?php
                                echo date('Y-m-d');
                                ?> />
```

Hope this helps